# Pyspark dataframe.where to filter but got missing rows

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I tried to remove row with `HVA_label_list` column length of 0, where `HVA_label_list` is a nested array column.

```
$ result.printSchema()
root
 |-- customer_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- HVA_label_list: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Then I check with the result first by converting it to pandas directly

```
$ result_pd = result.toPandas()
$ print(len(result_pd))
$ print(np.sum([len(i) for i in result_pd['HVA_label_list'].values]))
$ print(np.sum([len(i)>0 for i in result_pd['HVA_label_list'].values]))
$ result_pd.head()        

168866
37716
32913
   customer_id                               HVA_label_list
0  10125935022                                           []
1  10808619122                                           []
2  12143532522  [[VISIT_CHECKOUT_AMAZON_POINTS_PAGE, 0, 0]]
3  14471395022                                           []
4  14695903222                                           []
```

This looks fine. I should expect to have 32913 rows if I `filter` it right. Then I do this

```
result2 = result.where(size(col("HVA_label_list")) > 0)
result2_pd = result2.toPandas()
$print(len(result2_pd))

10636
```

I have no idea where could go wrong with this. Actually similar problem occurs when I try to explode `HVA_label_list`. where I only get around 10k row, but 37716 expected.

Comment: are there any `None` values in `HVA_label_list` column ?

Comment: @Frosty No, all empty ones are just empty array

Comment: The reason I asked is because in `spark` when you use `size` and if there is any `null` value in the column on which size is being applied it returns `-1` and that might not be the case while using `pandas` and hence the difference in the count because it's filtering all the `-1`s too in condition of `>0` what you can try is add one more condition for `-1` along with `>0` and see if the count is matching then. if it is then there are something up with data having size `-1`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to filter a Spark DataFrame to remove rows where the HVA_label_list column has a length of 0. You can do this by using the size function and the > operator in the where clause of a DataFrame filter transformation.

Comment: your code is exactly same as the OP posted at the end of the question